# Error LNK2028 and LNK2019 in Visual Studio 2008 C++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, linker-errors

I have done a lot of research to come around a linker error that I recieve in Visual Studio 2008. The code runs well in VS2010, but I need it to work in VS2008 as well.

The linker gives me the following output when building the projects:

```
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000459) "void __cdecl __ExceptionPtrCopy(void *,void const *)" (?__ExceptionPtrCopy@@$$FYAXPAXPBX@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::_Exception_ptr::_Exception_ptr(class std::_Exception_ptr const &)" (??0_Exception_ptr@std@@$$FQAE@ABV01@@Z) 

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl __ExceptionPtrCopy(void *,void const *)" (?__ExceptionPtrCopy@@$$FYAXPAXPBX@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::_Exception_ptr::_Exception_ptr(class std::_Exception_ptr const &)" (??0_Exception_ptr@std@@$$FQAE@ABV01@@Z)  

error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I think that the error occurs when I want to communicate from c++ to c++/cli. I have a managed class which holds a reference to a managed object.

ManagedWrapper.h:

```
class ManagedObjectWrapperPrivate
{
public:
msclr::auto_gcroot<ManagedObject^> obj;
}
public class ManagedWrapper
{
...
private:
ManagedObjectWrapperPrivate *objWrapper;
}
```

The object and object wrapper is then initialized in the constructor. However for the native c++ code not to see the managed objects, I redeclare (in NativeWrapper.h) as follows:

```
class ManagedObjectWrapperPrivate;
```

Hence, the native class won't know about the managed object that ManagedObjectWrapperPrivate holds.

This works fine in VS 2010, but seems not to work in VS2008

I'll be happy to provide further information if needed.

Comment: It's a linker error, not a compiler error. Afaik that function was introduced in VS2010, so if you get errors from it when building with VS2008 something's wrong with your build system. Can you post a minimal code sample that reproduces the error?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to add that the code is a wrapper that communicates to c++ VS2010 projects, that in turn communicates to VS2012 C# managed projects. I guess that this information helps.

Comment: well that kinda reveals where the problem lies, but you'll have to be *way* more specific - show some code, explain what kind of wrapper etc

Comment: I have added some code that I think is the cause. However, it is obvious from your previous example that it is due to the fact that VS2008 doesn't have the class used in the newer classes written in VS2010. Can this be treated somehow?

Comment: Not sure: you still don't properly show how your projects are setup. you say the wrapper communicates with VS2010 code; which part of the code you show is in VS2010 and which is in VS2012? Also the code you show won't compile due to missing `ref` keyword, I also don't see any `#using` or so to indicate you're importing managed code? But anyway: afaik 2008/2010 target different frameworks, so even if it would compile/link it wouldn't ever run.